# How to plot multple lines in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a data frame with 4 columns, all floating-point numbers. I would like to make a piecewise-line plot. Each curve will have 4 points, 1 curve per row of the dataframe. The x-values should be the values of the dataframe, the y-values the column indices.

In Python I would have done something like this

```
plt.figure()
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    plt.plot(data[i], [0,1,2,3], '*-')
plt.show()
```

I have spent an hour reading forums and trying out different arguments for `matplot` and `ggplot` but to no avail.

Here is the result of my python plot

[image]

I don't mind using other libraries like ggplot2 or other.

**Edit**: I forgot to specify an important additional requirement. All of the curves have to be sorted in the order of their column index. For example, consider the following plot

[image]

Here, the 3rd curve is not plotted correctly with respect to this additional requirement. Its y-indices go in the order [0, 2, 1, 3], whereas it should be [0, 1, 2, 3]. It is the X-axis that I would like to not be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, in Base R this is just the same as in Python.

```
clr <- hcl.colors(ncol(m))  ## define colors
plot.new(); plot.window(xlim=range(m), ylim=c(0, 3))  ## define plot area
for (i in seq_len(ncol(m))) lines(m[, i], 0:3, type='o', pch=20, col=clr[i])  ## loop
axis(1); axis(2); box()  ## axes and box
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
m <- sapply(0:10, \(i) c(-.5, .5, 1.5, 2.5) + i + rnorm(4, 0, .1))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `ggplot2` approach would require to first reshape your data to long using e.g. `tidy::pivot_longer`.

Using some fake example data

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

dat <- data.frame(
  "0" = seq(-1, 2, length.out = 10),
  "1" = 1 + seq(-1, 2, length.out = 10),
  "2" = 2 + seq(-1, 2, length.out = 10),
  "3" = 3 + seq(-1, 2, length.out = 10),
  check.names = FALSE
)

dat
#>             0         1        2        3
#> 1  -1.0000000 0.0000000 1.000000 2.000000
#> 2  -0.6666667 0.3333333 1.333333 2.333333
#> 3  -0.3333333 0.6666667 1.666667 2.666667
#> 4   0.0000000 1.0000000 2.000000 3.000000
#> 5   0.3333333 1.3333333 2.333333 3.333333
#> 6   0.6666667 1.6666667 2.666667 3.666667
#> 7   1.0000000 2.0000000 3.000000 4.000000
#> 8   1.3333333 2.3333333 3.333333 4.333333
#> 9   1.6666667 2.6666667 3.666667 4.666667
#> 10  2.0000000 3.0000000 4.000000 5.000000

dat |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-id,
    names_to = "y", values_to = "x"
  ) |>
  mutate(y = as.numeric(y)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = factor(id))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: If possible, I think there is still something not quite right. The problem is that the plotting sorts the data points with respect to X, whereas I want them to be sorted with respect to Y. For example, I added a line `dat[3, "2"] = 0.5`, and the third curve got sorted with respect to X. I'm sorry, I do realise I forgot to specify this explicitly in the original question

Comment: I am still highly interested in this answer. It would be good to know how to do this with `ggplot`.

Comment: Hi Aleksejs, sure. `geom_line` will connect the points in the order of the variable mapped on `x`. But you could change that by using `geom_line(orientation="y")` to connect in the order of the variable mapped on `y`. A second option would be to use `geom_path` which will connect observations in the order as they appear in the dataset.